# Subdomain redirect for folder with nginx

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

in my current lightspeed server I use the following htaccess code for redirect a folder to subdomain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^labs\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/labs/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://labs.example.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

But I'm planning to move to nginx, so what will be the equivalent nginx code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule in `nginx.conf`:

```
server {
    server_name ~^labs\.example\.com$
    location ~ ^/labs/(.*)$ {
       return 301 http://labs.example.com$1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. I will try and let you know. :) Thanks for the answer :)